# в CAT на абсолютном слое возможно передвижение всего скелета?

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax

help система кат в 3д максе ,нужно чтобы человек ходил а не шагал на месте на абсолютном слое,именно на абсолютном

Comment: А чем ходил отличается от шагал?

Comment: )))он на месте марширует у меня,надо чтоб он от точки а к точке б пошел)